# Dropdown select specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, event-handling

I have this code,

```
$('#Queue_QActionID').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '501' || $(this).val() == '502' || $(this).val() == '503' || $(this).val() == '504' || $(this).val() == '505' || $(this).val() == '506' || $(this).val() == '507' || $(this).val() == '110') {
        document.getElementById("actionparams").style.display = "block";
        //jQuery alternative
        //$("#attach").show();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("actionparams").style.display = "none";
        //jQuery alternative
        //$("#attach").hide();
    }
});

$(function () {
    console.log($('#Queue_QActionID').val());
    if ($('#Queue_QActionID').val() == '502') {

        $(".datepicker1").datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"

        })
        $(".datepicker2").datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
        })
    } else {
        $(".datepicker1").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',


        });

        $(".datepicker2").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
    }
});
```

and I want in the second function to select the value with the number `502` and when this happens then the `datepicker` should change from `datepicker` to `datetimepicker`.

I'm not really sure how I can do this. It seemed simple at first but now I'm stuck. How can I get a specific value and use if to display the result I want?

Note: the values are from a drop down list.

Comment: what is `Queue_QActionID`?

Comment: it's my drop down list

Comment: You should put that in the doc ready block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your code.

```
 $('#Queue_QActionID').change(function () {
if ($(this).val() == '501' || $(this).val() == '502' || $(this).val() == '503' || $(this).val() == '504' || $(this).val() == '505' || $(this).val() == '506' || $(this).val() == '507' || $(this).val() == '110') {
      $(".datepicker1").datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"

    });
    $(".datepicker2").datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
    });
} else {
    $(".datepicker1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',


    });

    $(".datepicker2").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
}
});
```

Comment: this doesn't help much. When I choose one of those values, in my original code it creates a box to pick dates. Hence, the id `#actionparams`. What I want is when I choose the value `502`, the box should change from simple datepicker to datepicker with time.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out.I did something like this and it seems to work:

```
 $('#Queue_QActionID').change(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == '501' || $(this).val() == '503' || $(this).val() == '504'
                   || $(this).val() == '505' || $(this).val() == '506' || $(this).val() == '507' || $(this).val() == '110') {
                document.getElementById("actionparams").style.display="block";


                //jQuery alternative
                //$("#attach").show();
            } 
            else {
                document.getElementById("actionparams").style.display="none";
                //jQuery alternative
                //$("#attach").hide();
            }
               if ($(this).val()=='502') {
                document.getElementById("actionparams1").style.display="block";

                $(".datepicker3").datetimepicker({
                    dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
                    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"

                })
                $(".datepicker4").datetimepicker({
                    dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
                    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
                })
            }
        });

    $(function() {

      $( ".datepicker1" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',


        });

      $( ".datepicker2" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'    
        });
     });
```

Comment: Good for you,  but, my eyes hurt!

Comment: haha you're right. It's not very good looking. I'm trying to "paint" it a little better than this!